# Copy Sharepoint data to SQL Server and then use the data for reporting purpose

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, sharepoint-2007, ssis

I have data in sharepoint which has 104 columns and 708 rows. This data is basically contains information about enterprise. The senior management wants to view different charts by using these data such as bar chart, pie chart, tabular, bubble chart etc., There are no specific number of charts as they can plot any column against anything. For instance grouping of applications by criticality in a pie chart.

In order to create these n number of reports what we thought is to transfer the sharepoint list to sql server (using SSIS) and then use sql server reporting services (SSRS) to generate those reports and then use an ASP .net front end to contain the reports.

The very first important question is whether we can transfer sharepoint list to SQL Server using SSIS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible to pull SharePoint data using SSIS but I have never done it personally. If you are using **`SSIS 2008`**, following links might help you.

[**SharePoint List Source and Destination**](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652)

[**Extracting and Loading SharePoint Data in SQL Server Integration Services**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd365137.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Our commercial product "[Enesys RS Data Extension](http://www.enesyssoftware.com)", a reporting services extension, lets your build reports directly from your SharePoint lists.
Not sure it would provide much benefits to transfer your list(s) to SQL Server first. If that's really what you would like to do however, the Standard and Enterprise editions also include "Enesys IS Data Extension" which offer a set of components for Integration Services.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "Connect to Access" button from a list to put a copy in Access and then use Access's export to ODBC Data Source to move it into a table in SQL. Very quick and easy.